# Explicit static initialization to zero in C++

Tags: c++, initialization

I am sorry to ask this trivial question but I could not find a definitive answer: if I have explicit static initialization to zero, is it zero initialization or initialization with constant expression? Say if I have

a.hpp:

```
class A { ... static int x; }
```

a.cpp;

```
int A::x = 0;
```

How many times will 0 be assigned to `x`? Once during zero initialization or twice during both zero initialization and initialization with constant expression?

Comment: How could you tell the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of the variable will be 0 before any of your code is executed.
How it gets that way depends largely on the system; one typical approach
is to read an image of the date from disk, when loading the program.
Formally, you have zero initialization, followed by static
initialization, but there's no way a conforming implementation can tell,
and I've never heard of an implementation that separates the two.

Under Unix, at least in its older and more traditional versions,
uninitialized static variables were placed in the bs segment,
statically initialized variables in the data segment.  The executable
file on the disk contained an image of the data segment, which was
copied into memory; all of the bytes in the bs segment were set to 0.
On a modern machine, with paged virtual memory, I would expect similar
behavior, with the difference that the initialization be deferred until
the page was first accessed.

I would be very surprised if Windows handled this differently (except for the names of the segments).

Comment: I was asking about c++ and it guarantees a very specific initialization order, the question was about details in this order.

Comment: And I answered that.  Formally, it's zero initialization, followed by static initialization, followed by dynamic initialization.  What happens before dynamic initialization, however, cannot be determined by a conforming program, so anything the system does which results in the correct values is fine.  Most systems do what I described.

Comment: Static initialization is performed in two steps and I am wondering which ones will be used here.

Comment: @zzz777 Static initialization, as defined in the standard, is a single step, following zero initialization.  Static initialization, in the more general sense, includes both.  As I said, formally zero initialization is the first step, then static initialization, but as there is absolutely no way for a program to tell, most implementations actually do the two in parallel.  When the program is loaded, before any user code is executed.